# Horizontal list view in android that can be fill from right to left (rtl)

Tags: android, listview, horizontal-scrolling

I need a Horizontal ListView that can working with `Adapters` and can be fill from righ to left. i see [`dev-smart`](http://dev-smart.com/?p=34) ListView and i work with it. it's good but i can't fill the items from right to left particular when items don't occupy whole width of ListView.
any other solution exist or is there a way for putting the items from right to left and scroll from left to right?

```
------------------------------------
             3333     22222     1111
------------------------------------
```

something like this.

Comment: Maybe you can do it left to right but let the adapter return the items in reverse order and make it scroll to the end in beginning?

Comment: order of displaying is not matter! i want to show items from right side of display to the left side.

Comment: have you found any solution ?

Comment: i don't find any good solution and i align the horizontallistview in center instead.

Comment: please check this answer:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728837/recyclerview-grow-element-from-right-to-left/46315909#46315909)