# Android - How to create Right-to-Left Horizontal-ListView with Recycleview?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I know, can use recycleview, that is not a problem. I can also use horizontalviews in recycleviews, that is not a problem also.But I failed to start loading the data start from right-most end, which I failed to do.
There is no binding that I have to use recycleview.
SO, I also tried horizontal listview also. But I could not load data from the right-most end with it, also.

Any kind of help will be appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this out http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Comment: Please check the description , I modified that. Thanks for replying.

Comment: please check this answer:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728837/recyclerview-grow-element-from-right-to-left/46315909#46315909)

Answer (score 0):

Set gravity of raw file layout to `end /right` it should work.

Comment: if you want to set alignment to right this is it. And if you want everything to start from right for every component in your Application set "application:rtl = true" in manifest application tag.